# jquery ui-icon and text alignment

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to align jquery ui-icons with text like following, but I notice that the icon is always a little bit higher up than the text. Is there a way to align them horizontally, perfectly?

```
<span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-bullet"> bullet text </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`vertical-align: middle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) is the attribute to align the text to the middle of the cell, however if you're trying to build ordered/unordered lists with a custom icon you may have an easier time with [`list-style:square inside url("your/image/path.jpg");`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style).

Another alternative would be to set the `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-bullet">` to `position: relative` and move it around with `top:5px` or however much you need to center it.

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/7vrTn/

Comment: Unfortunately, "however much you need to center it" will change from browser to browser.

Answer (score 0):

move the **text to the outer span** and use **vertical-align** on the **inner span**. The value depends on your font.

```
<span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-bullet" style="vertical-align:..."></span> bullet text </span>
```

`vertical-align:middle` worked for me for a font size of 12

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a button: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons , but ofcourse that depends on the context.

*-pike